# Affordance to encourage tablet user to touch textbox (to get onscreen keyboard) on touchscreen?

Tags: touch-screen, keyboard, ipad, onscreen-keyboard

We have a web app for brain injured stroke survivors to teach them typing.

We are able (with some effort :)  make the onscreen keyboard appear. But sometimes it goes away when they touch the *Enter* button on the keyboard. (Our developer has some logic to detect browser size change to detect the appearance/disappearance of the Onscreen keyboard, but obviously, this isn't foolproof.

It seems like the most elegant solution is, after maybe 5 seconds or so, to show some graphic to **encourage them to touch the textbox**.

A secondary (much less important) benefit is that if they don't type for 5 seconds (even if they have an external keyboard) this would indicate they should type.

I am also considering making the icon blink several times after another 5 seconds (so a total of 10 seconds without typing).

1. How does this seem?
2. Any better suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is the onscreen keyboard for a touchscreen?

Comment: Yes. ipad, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all—sorry for correcting—but what you're looking for is a **signifier**, not an affordance. An affordance is a "relationship" a user can have with an object, a signifier is the "signal". So, what you need in my mind is a CTA (call to action). Instead of thinking of this in terms of on-screen keyboard and when they appear and whatnot is to forget all about that and come up with a strong CTA.

I don't know how the UI behaves exactly but I'm guessing they're supposed to type in the name of the animal, object, etc. shown.

Why not simply show a field-like input area with a CTA like "type the name of the animal". That's a strong signifier and would ask the user to touch the screen which would make the keyboard appear.